# Selenium : Callback Java Method after javascript injection

Tags: java, selenium

I am tring to figure out how to do this with selenium and Java.

1/ Inject a javascript that display a simple button (OK I know)

2/ When the user click on the button, i want to calls a Java method (selenium side)

My question is :

Is something already implemented to do this with selenium ?
Maybe use the "wait" selenium methods for a behavior (my button click) and directly call my java method ?

Or do i necessarily need to embed a small java server and make a http request in javascript to call my java method ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: what does your code do till the button is clicked ?

Comment: I'am not quite sure what you want to do but from your description I think Selenium is not the right tool for your Job. 
Selenium is a tool to automate End-To-End Test of Web applications. It simply simulates a real enduser of your software.

Comment: @PDHide  Infact I want to inject some javascript UI (as we could do with a chrome extension). But by clicking on this UI i want to interact with my Java code (desktop side).

Comment: @JanSchmitz infact I want to inject some javascript UI (as we could do with a chrome extension). But by clicking on this UI i want to interact with my Java code (desktop side).

So i can install a embed java http server in my desktop app and make some http request... I know it will work. But I just wonder if there are other possibilities with selenium to interact between the Browser and the java side.

Comment: You can interact with backend using API only , using ajax calls do you have it setup